# Erro no cadastro

Tags: python, login

Bom, sou iniciante em python, estava tentando fazer um sistema basico de cadastro/login. Porem estive um problema na criação de contas, as contas são criadas na database normalmente, mas consigo apenas logar com a primeira conta criada, as outras contas da como inexistente.

obs: estou usando sqlite

Arquivos: db.py, conexao.py, login.py

## db.py

```
#importando módulo do SQlite
import sqlite3

class db():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conexao = sqlite3.connect('db1.db')
        self.createTable()

    def createTable(self):
        c = self.conexao.cursor()

        c.execute("""create table if not exists usuarios (
                     usuario text,
                     senha text)""")
        self.conexao.commit()
        c.close()
```

## conexao.py

```
from db import db
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import sys


class conexao(object):
    def __init__(self, usuario="", senha=""):
        self.info = {}
        self.usuario = usuario
        self.senha = senha

    def inserirDatabase(self):

        banco = db()
        try:

            c = banco.conexao.cursor()

            c.execute("""
            INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, senha)
            VALUES (?,?)
            """, (self.usuario, self.senha))

            banco.conexao.commit()
            c.close()

            return "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!"
        except:
            return "Ocorreu um erro na inserção do usuário"


    def verificarDatabase(self, usuario, senha):

        banco = db()
        try:

            c = banco.conexao.cursor()

            c.execute("SELECT * FROM usuarios")
            result = c.fetchall()

            for record in result:
                if usuario != record[0]:
                    print(record)
                    return 'Usuario incorreto'
                elif senha != record[1]:
                    print(record)
                    return 'Senha incorreta'
                else:
                    subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "logado.py"])

            banco.conexao.commit()
            c.close()
            return 0
        except:
            return 'Error'
```

## login.py

```
from conexao import conexao
from tkinter import *
from db import db

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.fonte = ("Verdana", "8")

        self.container6 = Frame(master)
        self.container6["padx"] = 20
        self.container6["pady"] = 5
        self.container6.pack()

        self.container7 = Frame(master)
        self.container7["padx"] = 20
        self.container7["pady"] = 5
        self.container7.pack()

        self.container2 = Frame(master)
        self.container2["padx"] = 20
        self.container2["pady"] = 5
        self.container2.pack()

        self.container9 = Frame(master)
        self.container9["pady"] = 15
        self.container9.pack()

        self.container10 = Frame(master)
        self.container10["pady"] = 10
        self.container10.pack()

        self.lblmsg = Label(self.container9, text="")
        self.lblmsg["font"] = ("Verdana", "9", "italic")
        self.lblmsg.pack()

        self.lblusuario = Label(self.container6, text="Usuário:", font=self.fonte, width=10)
        self.lblusuario.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.txtusuario = Entry(self.container6)
        self.txtusuario["width"] = 25
        self.txtusuario["font"] = self.fonte
        self.txtusuario.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.lblsenha = Label(self.container7, text="Senha:", font=self.fonte, width=10)
        self.lblsenha.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.txtsenha = Entry(self.container7)
        self.txtsenha["width"] = 25
        self.txtsenha["show"] = "*"
        self.txtsenha["font"] = self.fonte
        self.txtsenha.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.btnBuscar = Button(self.container2, text="Logar", font=self.fonte, width=10)
        self.btnBuscar["command"] = self.fazerLogin
        self.btnBuscar.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.btnBuscar = Button(self.container2, text="Cadastrar", font=self.fonte, width=10)
        self.btnBuscar["command"] = self.inserirCadastro
        self.btnBuscar.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.container1 = Frame(master)
        self.container1["pady"] = 10
        self.container1.pack()

    def fazerLogin(self):
        user = conexao()

        usuario = self.txtusuario.get()
        senha = self.txtsenha.get()

        self.lblmsg["text"] = user.verificarDatabase(usuario, senha)

        self.txtusuario.delete(0, END)
        self.txtsenha.delete(0, END)

        # Checar conta
        banco = db()
        c = banco.conexao.cursor()

        # lendo os dados
        c.execute("""
        SELECT * FROM usuarios;
        """)
        result = c.fetchall()

        for linha in result:
            if usuario == linha[0]:
                if senha == linha[1]:
                    quit()
        c.close()

    def inserirCadastro(self):
        user = conexao()

        user.usuario = self.txtusuario.get()
        user.senha = self.txtsenha.get()

        self.lblmsg["text"] = user.inserirDatabase()

        self.txtusuario.delete(0, END)
        self.txtsenha.delete(0, END)

root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nesse trecho aqui:

```
for record in result:
    if usuario != record[0]:
        print(record)
        return 'Usuario incorreto'
    elif senha != record[1]:
        print(record)
        return 'Senha incorreta'
    else:
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "logado.py"])
```

é que está o seu problema.  "Traduzindo" de Python para Português você diz aí:

```
para cada record nos resultados:
     se usuario for diferente de record[0]:
          pare a busca aqui e retorne "usuário incorreto"
```

Então - o programa faz exatamente e o que você mandou: ele compara usuário e senha com todos os que estiverem gravados no banco, desde o primeiro. Se o primeiro for diferente do que o par usuário/snha enviado, sua funçao já retorna erro.

O correto aí é já pedir para buscar no banco o usuário passado, e então comparar uma transformação da senha (sim -vocẽ não deve gravar a senha como vem do usuário no banco, e sim uma transformação dela, que permita comparações, mas não recuperar a senha original - mas isso pode deixar pra depois que fizer funcionar)

Então, em vez de:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM usuarios")
result = c.fetchall()
```

Faça:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=?", (usuario,))
result = c.fetchall()
if not result: 
    return 'Usuario incorreto'
usuario, senha = result[0]
if senha != senha:
    return 'Senha incorreta'
...
```

A grande diferença é que com essa busca, a query ao banco deve retornar apenas UM usuário, e o nome eu já sei que vai estar certo - só comparo a senha.

Uma outra dica não relacionada com a sua pergunta, é que a linha seguinte é uma prática bem pouco recomendável de qualquer forma:

```
 subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "logado.py"])
```

Todo esse trabalho para autenditca rum suário, para depois rexecutar um processo externo, sem sequer passar um parâmetro sobre qual é o usuário logado?

Em geral, você vai querer rodar que está no arquivo "logado.py" no mesmo programa em que fez o logi, não precisa de um programa separado. Implesmente importe o arquivo com `import logado`, e instânciae as classe e/ou invoque funções que estão naquele arquivo.